# Who wins this hand? with a flush in comunity cards

Tags: flush

could you help me? Thanks in advance

Comunity Cards: A K 8 7 3
Player 1: Q and 5
Player 2: A and Q

[image: Player 1: Q and 5 --- Player2: A and Q]

Comment: Best hand is A-K-Q-8-7 of spades. The other player is playing the board, A-K-8-7-3. Q beats the 8. Poker hands always have exactly 5 cards, no more, now fewer, and all of them count.

Answer (score 0):

The person with Q5 wins because they can make a better 5 card hand. Their hand is As, Ks, Qs, 8s, 7s for an Ace high flush with a King and a Queen, while the other person has an Ace high flush with King and an 8.